# GestureRecognizer and IBOutlet don't work together

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, iboutlet

I'm creating an iPhone app. In my main view, I have a subview. When I add a gesture recognizer to this subview, and I connect it to an action in my view controller, it works : the action method is called when the gesture is performed.

But when I connect my subview to an outlet in my view controller, suddenly, the gesture recognizer doesn't work anymore.

I have recreated this simple situation in a blank project, and here it works... Have you an idea about the origin of my problem please ?

Comment: If it works on a blank project, try and figure out what operations you were calling on the outlet that made it stop working. Maybe disabled user interaction? Changed alpha to 0? Add the relevant code and maybe someone can assist.

Comment: which code do you have implemented? please mention here so we can help you

Comment: are you adding the gesture after or into the viewDidLoad of your viewController? before the viewDidLoad is called your view has not be loaded yet so for example if you add the gesture in the 'init' the outlet is just a NULL pointer

Comment: It was a stupid mistake : I called a method which disabled userInteraction of my outlet in my viewDidLoad... sorry. And thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading your comment, I understand that the problem was indeed that you "messed" with the IBOutlet instance in your viewDidLoad as I presumed.